# Logout in AppAuth-Android

Tags: android, appauth

I have an Android app developed in JAVA. For this app I am using the [IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) as my STS and everything is working fine. But i couldn't find any implementation to logout in [AppAuth library](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android). Can anyone help me on this? I really need the logout option in my app, so the users can logout from the app when ever they want and log back in again.
Any ideas, samples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

I am the lead maintainer of AppAuth.

Logout is usually as simple as discarding the `AuthState` object, in order to forget the acquired tokens. If you are referring to also signing the user out of the OpenID identity globally, there is a draft standard for this:

http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html

AppAuth does not support this, as we do not wish to include in-progress standardization work in the core library. It would be relatively simple to write an extension library to fulfill this particular purpose.

The documentation for IdentityServer4 on logout [is empty](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signout.html), so I don't know what mechanism they provide for logout and whether it follows any particular standard (draft or otherwise). I suggest you contact the developers of IdentityServer4 for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As of august 2018, the logout is still in draft (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#RPLogout). Does that mean that AppAuth still recommends to simply discard the AuthState Object ?

Comment: AppAuth-iOS recently added some support for logout that we intend to replicate in the Android implementation, which is mostly contingent on supporting generalized browser request dispatch and response handling.

Comment: Any updates on AppAuth-Android's support for logout?

Comment: An update to this answer would be great. Am I right in thinking using `prompt: "login"` is the recommended way of handling?

Answer (score 3):

You can add `.setPrompt("login")` to `AuthorizationRequest.Builder`, and it will ask for credentials again.
According to OpenId [docs](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#rfc.section.3.1.2.1)

https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/issues/215

Comment: this approach does not maintain the persisting of the user using the keep me signed in option. If propmt is set to login. you will not see the keep me signed in checkbox below. Meaning everythime the authorise endpoint is called, the user will need to enter their username and password instead of automatically logging them in

Comment: I thought this would solve my problem too.  But the authentication server is free to ignore this request.  And in my experience they usually do.  Sigh.